# How to add page number in Aspose Words for .NET without using DocumentBuilder?

Tags: aspose.words

I'm using **DOM** way to build the Document from **XHTML**. How would I add Page number in a header or footer without **DocumentBuilder** approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [DOM](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Inserting+Fields+using+DOM), you can use appendChild() and appendField() methods to add page numbering in header/footer. Below is an example.

```
// Load your document
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document("document.docx");
// Get the primary footer
Aspose.Words.HeaderFooter hf = doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary];
// Get the first paragraph of footer
Aspose.Words.Paragraph para = hf.FirstParagraph;
// Add current page number field
para.AppendField("PAGE");
// Add a / character
para.AppendChild(new Run(doc, "/"));
// Add total page numbers field
para.AppendField("NUMPAGES");
```

I work with Aspose as a Developer Evangelist.